# How can i move to the next scene with cross_hairs in python asciImatics?

Tags: python, animation, scene, asciimatics, cross-hair-label

Im new to using asciimatics, and im playing around with it to make a game. However, when i add a cross_hairs to a scene, it wont move to the next scene. How can i move to the next scene when i have cross_hairs?

Comment: Hard to say when there is no "cross hairs" code in asciimatics...  You may want to share a simple app that shows the problem.

Comment: Check out the advice here for adding code...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the code is based off of your sample code- interactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using something very similar to [this sample](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/blob/master/samples/interactive.py), asciimatics is playing a Scene with 2 or more Sprites.

If so, this sample already allows you to move to the next Scene by pressing space.  Job done!  :-)

In a little more detail...  It relies on the default [global key handler](https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/widgets.html#global-key-handling) to do this.  As covered [here](https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/widgets.html#exceptions), it just raises the NextScene exception to tell asciimatics to move on.

If you want to move to a new Scene based off a different event (e.g. the cross hairs hitting another Sprite), you should just raise that Exception at the time you detect the condition.